# Pandas Series.values sometimes returns numpy.ndarray, other times returns pandas.core.arrays.floating.FloatingArray

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm using Pandas 1.2.4 on Python 3.8.  I passed two columns of a DataFrame to a function as two arguments, x and y.  My intention is to model y = f(x), but Numpy's `lstsq()` was complaining about the data types I was passing to it, thus:

```
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc lstsq_n
```

Digging deeper, in debug mode, I've come across a Pandas behavior and object type I haven't encountered before.  Here's some output from my debug session:

```
>>> type(x)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

>>> type(x.values)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

>>> type(y)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

>>> type(y.values)
<class 'pandas.core.arrays.floating.FloatingArray'>
```

It appears that Numpy doesn't know what to do with these Pandas `FloatingArray` objects.  I'm not exactly sure what this different object type might be.  Both columns in my original DataFrame are populated with floating-point numbers; there are no `NaN` values.

I have a clunky workaround for getting `y` into a Numpy-compatible form: `numpy.array(y.values, dtype=float)`.  With this, I can proceed with my curve fitting.

However, I would like to understand why these gymnastics are necessary.  Thanks!

Comment: Looking up `pd.core.arrays.floating.FloatingArray`, it appears to be an experimental class that handles missing values.  It prints like `[<NA>, 1.0, <NA>, <NA>, 4.0]`.  `np.array(x)` produces an object dtype array with `<NA>` elements, which is probably giving `lstsq` problems.

Comment: `S.astype(float).values` gives floats array with `nan` instead of `<NA>`.